# Numpy replace values

Tags: python, numpy

I got an rgb image (h and w are not constant) and I want to paint green all the pixels that are within certain range (rgb range).
I got most of the code working, the thing i struggle with:
assume I got the following image:

```
arr = np.zeros((4,4,3))
arr[0,0] = [2,3,4]
arr[1, 1] = [1, 2, 3]
```

lets assume the condition is all the pixels that meet the following rule:

```
t = np.all((arr >= [1,2,3])&(arr <= [1,4,4]),axis = 2)
print(t)
[[False False False False]
[False  True False False]
[False False False False]
[False False False False]]
```

each value in t represents a pixel in arr, if it's true i want to change the corresponding pixel in arr to be [10,10,10].
meaning i want the output to be:

```
[[[2. 3. 4.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [10. 10. 10.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Im asking for a numpy-ish way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to do:

```
arr[t] = [10,10,10]
```

Example:

```
>>> arr = np.zeros((4,4,3))
>>> arr[0,0] = [2,3,4]
>>> arr[1,1] = [1,2,3]
>>> t = np.all((arr >= [1,2,3])&(arr <= [1,4,4]),axis = 2)
>>> arr[t] = [10,10,10]
>>> arr
array([[[ 2.,  3.,  4.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [10., 10., 10.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: @YaronScherf you should check your `t`, I added the complete example from your OP and it works.